# Integral of a square compared to the square of an integral

Tags: integration, analysis, functional-analysis

What can be said about a complex valued, continuous function $f$, defined on $[0,1]$, such that:
$$
\int_0^1{|f|^2}=\left|\int_0^1{f}\right|^2 
$$
I encountered this form as part of an exercise. Obviously, the above holds for any constant $f$, and it seems intuitive that the converse also holds (i.e. that if the above equality is true, then $f$ is constant), but I could not prove it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @GPerez No, both absolute values are complex.

Comment: What you are trying to prove is false. The $L^2$ norm  does not equal the $L^1$ norm in general for constant functions. Notice that $\int C^2 =(b-a)C^2$ whereas $(\int C )^2 = (b-a)^2 C^2$.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. I corrected the question.

Comment: This can also be proven using Parsevals theorem.

Comment: Also look for "Jensen's Inequality".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a case of equality in the   [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)
$$\left|\int_{0}^1 f\overline g\right|^2\leq \int_0^1 |f|^2\int _0^1|g|^2 $$
where $g=1$ is a constant function. And the equality holds if and only if $f$ and $g$ are dependent,i,e $f$ is a scalar multiple of $g$.

---

Note that when we change the bounds to $a,b$, the equality in question is not true for constants functions $f$